# Returning a C# object when function is called from JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, object, winjs

I'm working on a WinJS Windows app and need to write some C# to multithread some of the data parsing because it slows the app significantly. I am hoping to write a C# function which will make a web service call, parse the data in order to keep track of a whole bunch of properties (some ints, arrays or lists, strings, etc), and then return all of those properties to be used by the JavaScript.

Is there a way to return a C# Object or dictionary and have it be usable as a JavaScript object?

Comment: [Json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Comment: Yup, convert your c# object into json and parse it with Javascript

Comment: You should look at `JSON` or `JSON.NET`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can create your own [Windows Runtime Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230301.aspx) in C# and call it from your javascript code.

Having said that I don't think you need it for your scenario. You can call your service with an instance of the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) client class. If the service returns json data you can just call `JSON.parse` in order to get an object that represents the returned data.